# How to save richboxtext content to .txt file via saveFiledialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to create a simple notepad for my self.
At the moment i have created a button where i can Open file and get content. 
How can i create a Save file button so every line of my richboxtext goes to new .txt file?

I want that i can save to a file name of my choice not a static one so i use SaveFileDialog.

This is what i have for Open File.

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Stream plusma = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();

    string faila_nosaukums = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    string faila_teksts = File.ReadAllText(faila_nosaukums);
    rtf_NotePad.Text = faila_teksts;
}
```

Nothing up for Save file at the moment:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

**----------Updated-----------------**
Saving file:

```
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
            saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                rtf_NotePad.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
```

Adding color:

```
            colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            rtf_NotePad.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
```

Comment: You can use one of [`RichTextBox.SaveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads.

Comment: rtf_NotePad.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); This worked for me. Is it right?

Comment: What do you want to create?  a wordpad-like application or notepad-like?

Comment: You are saving plain text and then setting the color. `rtf_NotePad.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;` sets the color of whole rich text to the selected color.

Comment: `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` saves the file in plain text, like notepad.

Comment: without RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText it throw's me an error and doesn't open or save. Error: File format is not valid.

Comment: Okay i got it , i just need to use RichText instead of PlainText.

Comment: Good job, You can accept one of answers and vote for both of them if you found them helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`RichTextBox.SaveFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    rtf_NotePad.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Also, there exists a similar method for opening the file. It is the [`RichTextBox.LoadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Use it like this:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    rtf_NotePad.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Does this work when i work with Fonts / Colors ? I created a button Format Font. When i change font in my program , after saving and opening it again it doesn't show up the font , just a simple text.

Comment: Use the exact code as in my answer for both loading and saving. It will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SaveFile(String, RichTextBoxStreamType)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1(v=vs.110).aspx) method of your rich text box and and pass `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` as second parameter.

Also if you want to let the user choose to save in `.txt` format or `.rtf`:

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
saveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    if(extension.ToLower()==".txt") /*saveFileDialog.FilterIndex==1*/
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    else
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

You should know `.rft` format is different from `.txt` format.
If you save in `.rtf` format, the formatting including font and color remains, but if you save in `.txt` format, it only saves the plain text. And if you want to simulate notepad, you don't need to use `.rtf` format.

Another point is if you want to have only the `Font` option like notepad, the font option would be a `User Settings` that can be saved via `Settings.settings`. Then you can set that font for your `TextBox`/`RichTextBox` after application loads. This way you can save the file in `.txt` format.

Comment: Even if i save in .rtf it doesn't show Font/Colors after i open the .rtf file in the same program or any other .rtf program.

Comment: If you need to work with `.rtf` you should load using `LoadFile` method. As mentioned by Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ in his post.

Comment: If you are creating a wordpad-like application you need to use `.rtf` but if you are creating a notepad-like application, you need `.txt` (Also you can use `TextBox`)

Comment: I already did like Farhan said. Updated my question so you can see. It doesn't matter saving .rtf in .txt it doesn't show any color.

Comment: What do you want to create? a wordpad-like application or notepad-like? You are saving plain text and then setting the color. `rtf_NotePad.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;` sets the color of whole rich text to the selected color.

Comment: wordpad-like application i guess. I set color before i save file. I have buttons like "Format text" , "Text Color" , "Save file".