# RTF code saved when I save a txt file

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

I'm working on a VB.NET project.

I have a richtextbox and a button to save what I write.

But when I open the file I see this:

[image]
I want to show just the text "ilyasscj isjdivs", not all the RTF code.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub EnsregistrerSousToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As 
System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
EnsregistrerSousToolStripMenuItem.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Texte|*.txt|RTF|*.rtf|Tous|*.*"
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "enregistrer un fichier"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fich = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(fich)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub EnregistrerToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As 
System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
EnregistrerToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If fich = "" Then
        SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Texte|*.txt|RTF|*.rtf|Tous|*.*"
        SaveFileDialog1.Title = "enregistrer un fichier"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            fich = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
            Try
                RichTextBox1.SaveFile(fich)
            Catch ex As Exception
                '    MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    Else
        Try
            RichTextBox1.SaveFile(fich)
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            MsgBox(ex2.Message)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you should not use a "rich" textbox?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation or paid any attention to Intellisense to see if there is an alternative way to use SaveFile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save richboxtext content to .txt file via saveFiledialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568883/how-to-save-richboxtext-content-to-txt-file-via-savefiledialog)

Comment: Are you opening your file in Notepad? If so, notepad is only capable of showing plain text. Try opening your file in your application with `RichTextBox1.Load(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

The [RichTextBox.SaveFile(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) pre-defined behaviour is described in the documentation:

> Saves the contents of the RichTextBox to a rich text format (RTF)
>   file.

If you define more format options in the `SaveFileDialog`, you also need to verify what format the User chose and instruct the `SaveFile` method to use that format when streaming the output to disk.
As an example, use a `Select Case` switch to select the [RichTextBoxStreamType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1%29%3Bk%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) corresponding to the User choice (see the documentation for the meaning of other possible fomat options):

```
Dim sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
sfd.Filter = "Texte (*.txt)|*.txt|RTF (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Tous (*.*)|*.*"
sfd.Title = "Enregistrer un fichier"
sfd.DefaultExt = "txt"

If sfd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim Filter As Integer = sfd.FilterIndex
    Dim FileFormat As RichTextBoxStreamType
    Select Case Filter
        Case 1
            FileFormat = RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText
        Case 2
            FileFormat = RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText
        Case Else
            FileFormat = RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText
    End Select

    Dim FileName As String = sfd.FileName
    RichTextBox1.SaveFile(FileName, FileFormat)
End If
```